# react-slide-toggle Remove overflow hidden when onExpanded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The last element of my slideToggle is select. When select opened options inside don't visible, because parent block with `overflow: hidden` which provide react-slide-toggle. I need `overflow: visible` when opening finished, and reverse when closing started.

I don't understand how to use onExpanded for diong this.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slide-toggle#component-usage-example-with-all-options

Assume that the parent element whose overflow you wish to set has the id "parentElement".

Then add the following props to the SlideToggle

```
    onExpanding={({ range, progress, hasReversed }) => {
    /* optional event hook */

        document.getElementById("parentElement").style.overflow = "visible"


    }}

    onCollapsed={({ hasReversed }) => {
    /* optional event hook */
       document.getElementById("parentElement").style.overflow = "hidden";
    }}
```

Please test the above code and tell me the outcome.

Comment: Thank you. But I have a lot of slideToggle elements which generates from the server. I need smth like this:  this.closest(".block").style.overflow = "visible", but this is mistake. Each slideToggle have his own parent ".block"